# Openpyxl: filling column with formulas

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to copy this formula =IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D2,Control!$J$3:$J$914,0),"YES",),"NO") that starts in row 2, but column BJ in excel.

I want to make this formula go to the last row which is 31693

```
for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(sheet2.columns)[62]):
if row != 0:
    n = '=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D%d,Control!$J$3:$J$914,0),"YES",),"NO")' % (row+1, row+1)
    cellObj.value = n
```

when I ran this code I got an error message saying not all arguments converted during string formatting. Not sure what to fix

Comment: The error is because you are passing two arguments to your `%` format string when you only have one place you are formatting, the `%d` in the string. Either you are missing another place for your second argument in the format string, or you need to remove the second argument.

Comment: That's a terrible way to loop over column 63.